# Why am I getting "the application is failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, blender

I encountered an error while installing blender 2.49b. The error is:

> the application is failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

I'm running Windows 7 (64-bit). How can I install the program?

Answer (score 1):

You should try searching the Blender forums first. Sure enough:

http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16128&highlight=sidebyside&sid=d3510edab9b77be5db33b1c8024de296

and

http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15309&highlight=sidebyside&sid=d3510edab9b77be5db33b1c8024de296

If you can't be bothered clicking the links, the solution is to download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=ba9257ca-337f-4b40-8c14-157cfdffee4e&displayLang=en)